# ¿Cómo desplazar un elemento con curva?

Tags: css

Tengo un div y un pseudo-elemento que sale del div, se dirige al punto A (a la izquierda), va al punto B (arriba y centro) y termina en el punto C (a la derecha). El movimiento lo hace muy lineal y me gustaría que hiciera una curva, como una semicircunferencia, ovalada o circular...

Pongo aquí mi código:

```css
div {
    margin: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background: steelblue;
}
div p {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.vuelta:hover:before {
    content: '';    
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    left: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
 
    -webkit-animation: 5s moverobjeto infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moverobjeto {
    10% {
        left: -75px;
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        left: -75px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -25px;
        top: -50px;
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -25px;
        top: -50px;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        left: 175px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -25px;
    }
    60% 
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        left: 175px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="vuelta"><p>Media vuelta</p></div>
</body>
```

El movimiento que hace el cuadrado es muy recto, me gustaría que fuera curvado pasando del punto A al B y luego al C

Cómo lo podría conseguir?

Gracias!